# Optimización sentencias SQL

Tags: sql

He creado estas dos queries en `SQL` para un cuadro de `power bi`:

`SQL` 1:

```
SELECT *

FROM   dwho.hpedventa_dwho_v AS p 
   INNER JOIN dimensiones.agentes d 
           ON d.agente_sk = p.agente_sk 
              AND agente_id = '000995'

   INNER JOIN dimensiones.clientes c
           ON c.cliente_sk = p.cliente_sk
              AND cliente_id = '008984'
```

`SQL` 2:

```
SELECT *

FROM   dwho.hpedventa_dwho_v AS p 
   INNER JOIN dimensiones.agentes d 
           ON d.agente_sk = p.agente_sk 

   INNER JOIN dimensiones.clientes c
           ON c.cliente_sk = p.cliente_sk

WHERE agente_id = '000995' AND cliente_id = '008984'
```

Bueno, la primera pregunta es si el resultado va a ser el mismo.
En caso afirmativo, ¿alguna de las dos es mejor que la otra? ¿Hay alguna forma de medir su rendimiento?

Aprovecho para pediros consejos o best practices para optimizar las sentencias.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Al menos el *estándar* es el que usas en la segunda consulta. En cuanto al rendimiento, las puedes probar las dos. Si usas MySQL escribes `EXPLAIN` antes de ambas consultas y analizas los resultados. Por cierto, conviene que [edites la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/166977/edit) poniendo el manejador de base de datos que estás usando. Otra cosa que recomendaría es que uses los alias de tabla **siempre** en este tipo de consultas, también en las columnas del `WHERE`.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. La estoy usando para traerme la información a `Power BI`. 

¿Entonces las dos son correctas? ¿Ninguna es mejor que la otra?

Comment: SÍ, ambas son correctas y, al menos en MySQL, el plan de ejecución es el mismo en ambas consultas.

Comment: Por lo general no debe haber problemas de rendimiento entre una y otra, aunque siempre todo depende de los índices de las tablas y de otras circunstancias. Una respuesta definitiva sólo podrías tenerla haciendo pruebas de rendimiento reales con cada consulta. [Esta respuesta en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1019006/5587982), confirma más o menos lo que he dicho en anteriores comentarios. Los comentarios en esa respuesta también son interesantes.

Comment: Algo que puedes hacer como buena practica seria no utilizar * y escribir solo los campos que vas a utilizar y también podrías generar esa consulta en un Stored Procedure ya que si la envías desde un lenguaje de tipo servidor cada vez que se lance, el motor de base de datos la compilara y como esa consulta no va a cambiar (salvo en los id) ya que la tengas en un SP no se tendrá que compilar cada vez que se ejecute